# Strange behavior in mySQL 8 with order by, limit and parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

Supposing I have a table with the following values

[image]

I perform the following query and get the attached results

```
SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval;
```

[image]

Everything is good so far. I will now add a LIMIT statement.

```
SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval LIMIT 3;
```

[image]

Still everything looks good. But watch what happens when I add a parentheses to the query.

```
(SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) LIMIT 3;
```

[image]

Any ideas on why the parentheses causes the order to be incorrect. It would seem that the use of parentheses would only serve to ensure that the inner query is completed, and therefore ordered, prior to the limit being applied. But it appears that it causes the limit to be applied and ordering to be completely discarded. Is this a bug? A known bug? I did not see anything reported.

This came about because of a recent upgrade from MySQL5.5 to MySQL8 and how they handle UNION queries that contain order by and/or limit operations. Perhaps too many parentheses are being used regardless of if they are part of a union. Some of our SQL is generated so there may be cases where the parentheses are added by the engine automatically anticipating that the result might be used in a larger unioned query. Anyway. I digress from the core question.

EDIT/UPDATE:

As nbk and nick pointed out the use of parentheses, however innocuous they may seem in this instance, causes MySQL to handle this as a subquery. However, the following query actually works which seems contrary to the explanation given.

```
SELECT root.* FROM (SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) AS root LIMIT 3;
```

[image]

Now this is in the full form of a subquery however it would appear that it does apply the sorting in the subquery and then limits the results.

EDIT 2:

Following up on Nick's response. Yes, this is an example of an actual query that has been simplified for clarity and uses mock data to keep from leaking sensitive real data.

I think I have my answer to the original question which is essentially "MySQL has decided to optimize this as a subquery and therefore ignore the ORDER BY". This brings me to a head scratcher. Why are the following queries handled differently when they would appear to be functionally equivalent.

```
(SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) LIMIT 3;

SELECT root.* FROM (SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) AS root LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering inside subqueries/derived tables does not affect the final output; those rows are ordered *only* by the outer level `ORDER BY` clause. Since you don't have one, the ordering of your results in the last query is indeterminate. It would work properly if written as

```
(SELECT * FROM testvalues) ORDER BY textval LIMIT 3;
```

There is a description of this behaviour in the [MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/).

Note that when you try a "real" subquery i.e.

```
SELECT root.* FROM (SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) AS root LIMIT 3
```

The optimiser will propagate the `ORDER BY` clause because it meets the conditions described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html):

> The optimizer propagates an ORDER BY clause in a derived table or
>   view reference to the outer query block if these conditions are all
>   true:
>
> - The outer query is not grouped or aggregated.
> - The outer query does not specify DISTINCT, HAVING, or ORDER BY.
> - The outer query has this derived table or view reference as the only source in the FROM clause.

When these conditions are not true:

> Otherwise, the optimizer ignores the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Edited/Updated with additional information that seems to contradict the explanation given.

Comment: @BrianMueller but does represent the way you are using it? That query can be optimised into just the subquery...

Comment: If you are asking if the original question represents an actual usage - Yes it does (the table was generated as an example to keep from leaking sensitive data however it's an accurate example of a real query). The developer working on the issue found that if he made it into a "real subquery" that the results worked as expected. When I presented the answers from here he pushed back with his example that when he changed it to a "real subquery" it seemed to contradict the rule as given. Also, sure we can optimize it into a single query - but the question related to code that exists now in prod.

Comment: @BrianMueller See my edit. The manual says that for the "real subquery" you posted the optimiser will propagate the `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query. Presumably your existing query does not meet these three conditions?

Comment: So, the core reason is that A) MySQL determines that the query as written is a SUBQUERY based on the parentheses however B) it does not propagate the ORDER BY into the outer query because it does not meet all of the 3 rules given. Further, it's likely that the rule it does not meet is the 3rd rule because it cannot infer the FROM (although it clearly makes one up) it is indeterminate that the derived table is the only source in the from clause. Thank you for all the parts of the puzzle.

Comment: @BrianMueller yes, although I think the 3rd rule doesn't match because the outer query doesn't have a `FROM` clause at all... We'd probably have to go diving into the source code to figure out exactly which it was.

Answer (score 1):

As told here hundreds of times your parenthesis make that to a subquery  and therefore a table and for that:

> A "table" according to the SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a
>   table (or in a subquery in the FROM clause) do not come in any
>   specific order. That's why the optimizer can ignore the ORDER BY
>   clause that you have specified.

Source

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

But it is valid if course also for mysql.

I personylly think your question is answered.

But for your second question.

You should always look into the explain function of mysql, as you can see it uses in this case **filesort**.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `testvalues` (
> numval INT ,
> `textval` VARchar(2) );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `testvalues` (numval,textval)
> VALUES (1,'a'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(4,'d'),(2,'b'),(5,'e'),(8,'h'),(3,'c');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * From testvalues;
> ```
>
> ```
> numval | textval
> -----: | :------
>      1 | a      
>      6 | f      
>      7 | g      
>      4 | d      
>      2 | b      
>      5 | e      
>      8 | h      
>      3 | c
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN SELECT root.* FROM (SELECT * FROM testvalues ORDER BY textval) AS root LIMIT 3;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra         
> -: | :---------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | testvalues | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |    8 |   100.00 | Using filesort
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=998b4c5c5e942c4c8efb3312e823cf46)*

Comment: Edited/Updated with additional information that seems to contradict the explanation given.

Comment: Although I did not post it here I had already performed an explain and knew that one was actually performing a sort and the other was not. I also ran profiling and could see that one included a "sorting result" and "creating sort index" while the other did not. However, this was not useful information as it was already clear that one was sorting and the other was not. The real answer and the key to the solution had less to do with the subquery it would seem and more to do with the ability of the MySQL engine to infer information in some cases and not in others.